# Optimize counting sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given that the input will be N numbers from 0 to N (with duplicates) how I can optimize the code bellow for both small and big arrays:

```
void countingsort(int* input, int array_size)
{
    int max_element = array_size;//because no number will be > N

    int *CountArr = new int[max_element+1]();

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        CountArr[input[i]]++;

    for (int j = 0, outputindex = 0; j <= max_element; j++)
        while (CountArr[j]--)
            input[outputindex++] = j;

    delete []CountArr;
}
```

Having a stable sort is not a requirement.

**edit:** In case it's not clear, I am talking about optimizing the algorithm.

Comment: There’s nothing particularly standing out as inefficient here, but do use `std::vector` instead of raw pointers. And take care about off-by-one errors.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Is there a way to avoid using an extra array?

Comment: Why not use std::sort?

Comment: @Joel: because it's slower.

Comment: If the function is called multiple times you might gain some speed by reusing the same array for counter. In this case std::vector would be convenient for handling resizing.

Comment: Why do you need to go so fast that the difference matters? Might save the question from being closed. Compiler optimizers do well on code like this. Make sure you're using `-O3` for `gcc` or the equivalent for your compiler. It might go a tiny bit faster loading `CountArry[j]` into an `int` and decrementing that rather than the array element. But this is a super micro optimization. Whatever improvement accrues in this manner is likely to be very machine-dependent.

Comment: @Gene: please see edit

Comment: You still haven't said why the difference matters. It's impossible to do better asymptotically. Optimizing constant factors _is_ micro-optimization.

Comment: If you want suggestions about optimizations, it would be helpful, if you provide a meaningful benchmark

Comment: Quickly generating histograms (which is what the first step here is) is not so easy in practice. See for example [this long explanation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18gs0bkEwQ5cO8pMXT_MsOa8Xey4NEavXq-OvtdUXKck/pub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO there's nothing wrong here. I highly recommend this approach when max_element is small, numbers sorted are non sparse (i.e. consecutive and no gaps) and greater than or equal to zero.

A small tweak, I'd replace new / delete and just declare a finite array using heap, e.g. 256 for max_element.

```
int CountArr[256] = { }; // Declare and initialize with zeroes
```

As you bend these rules, i.e. sparse, negative numbers you'd be struggling with this approach. You will need to find an optimal hashing function to remap the numbers to your efficient array. The more complex the hashing becomes the benefit between this over well established sorting algorithms diminishes.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of complexity this cannot be beaten. It's `O(N)` and beats standard `O(NlogN)` sorting by exploiting the extra knowledge that `0<x<N`. You cannot go below `O(N)` because you need at least to swipe through the input array once.